# WPF data grid, how to create "left side" header?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I've tried different things, and I'd like to know how to add the row counter to the left of the data grid? (like we see in excel)

I see its possible:

[image]

but I dont know how to achieve this.

I admit I'm a newb when it comes to WPF, but in object properties there's not a "checkbox" to activate it, and so far I didnt come across any explicit code for it, so I'm not sure if its simple, or some elaborate hack.

ty.

Comment: Well it's not simple, but it's not exactly a hack either. It'll be more or less a custom control that you'd have to make. I don't think you should worry about that until you have a stronger footing in WPF. (Speaking as someone who just recently switched from winforms to WPF).

Comment: Thanks. I'll work on my WPF basics. I was hoping this to be a "checkbox" thing, instead of making my own custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a full code sample available on how to do this available on the following link.

**Adding right-aligned row numbers to a DataGridRowHeader in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/08/18/right-aligned-row-numbers-datagridrowheader-wpf/

You could put a `TextBlock` in the `RowHeaderTemplate` of the `DataGrid` and use a converter to get the index of the row:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mm.WpfApplication1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:RowNumberConverter x:Key="converter"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow},
                        Converter={StaticResource converter}}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        ...
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

But this approach will only work then virtualization is disabled or when you have only a few rows in your `ItemsSource`. If you want display the row numbers correctly but still keep the `DataGrid`'s default virtualization and recycling behaviour, you could handle the `LoadingRow` event for the `DataGrid` to set the `Header` property of the `DataGridRow` to the row number and then bind to this property in the `RowHeaderTemplate`.

Also note that if the `DataGrid` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>` and you are adding or removing items to/from it dynamically at runtime, the row numbers won't get updated until you start to scroll and the `LoadingRow` event is fired again.

To fix this, you could hook up an event handler to the `ItemsChanged` event of the `ItemContainerGenerator` of the `DataGrid` in the view and reset the `Header` property of all `DataGridRow` elements that are currently in the visual tree when this event occurs.

Please refer to the above link for more information and and a full working sample.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DataTable to fill the DataGrid and then use a

**MainWindow**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
                  DataTable tab = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            tab.Columns.Add("col " + i.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            DataRow r = tab.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                r[j] = "row " + (i).ToString() + "-col " + (j).ToString();
            tab.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        dg.ItemsSource = tab.AsDataView();  
    }
```

**Xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:HeaderConverter x:Key="headerConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dg">
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock MinWidth="30" TextAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource headerConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                            <Binding Path="Item" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**Converter**

```
public class HeaderConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int ind = -1;
        DataView dv = values[0] as DataView;
        if (dv != null)
        {
            DataRowView drv = values[1] as DataRowView;
            ind = dv.Table.Rows.IndexOf(drv.Row);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Collections.IEnumerable ien = values[0] as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
            ind = IndexOf(ien, values[1]);
        }
        if (ind == -1)
            return "";
        else
            return (ind + 1).ToString();
    }
    static int IndexOf(System.Collections.IEnumerable source, object value)
    {
        int index = 0; 
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (item.Equals(value))
                return index;
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: `RowHeaderTemplate` is the correct way to do this, but your row numbering will not work if the DataGrid is bound to a [*CollectionViewSource*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the point. That was a quick example, I updated the answer.

Comment: @Lucano Deskovic: Note that the ``IEnumerable `` part of the Converter can handle the DataTable too, but it does not keep the Indexes in sorting. That's why I separate that part by an if.

Comment: thanks, mm8s answer was sufficient,but this gives me some more brain food! TY!